# Extracting a function of a variable from an expression

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, fractions, partial-fractions

I have this expression:
$\frac{d+2wd}{2w+3wd-3d-w^2-1}$

Is there anyway I can write it just as a function of f(d)?

[To me this looks like it is already a function of d, but I want to confirm if what I'm thinking is correct and if not, how can I separate the w from this, if it is possible?]

Comment: Yes it is already a function of $d$. A function can be viewed as a "machine" that maps an input to an output. You give it an input, the machine gives you an output. How the machine manipulates your input is up to the "machine". It can work according to a formula, as in your case. It can even do some complicated algorithm which can not be described by a formula. A function just maps an input to an output, according to a given mapping rule.

Comment: Do you understand what I want to say? I think you see a function as something that changes expressions but that is not what a function is. A function takes an input, and delivers an output. It eats expressions from a certain form e.g. Real numbers (they first get evaluated before they really enter) and spits out expressions (usually numbers).

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I thought the same. However, w is a variable in actuality so is there a way for me to separate d and w or would it be impossible? My prof told me to write it as a function of d so he might have meant write f(d) instead of the whole long expression. I'll check with him.

Comment: Ah both are variables, ok, nice, didn't know that.

Comment: Normally you should write it then as a function of $d$ and $w$, namely $f(d,w) = \frac{d+2wd}{2w+3wd-3d-w^2-1}$, but he maybe asks whether you can write it as just $f(d)$?

Comment: I guess you should take just one value for $w$ then, question is which value. Or do you need to some for one reason over all values of $w$, then you can take an integral or a sum. Don't know where exactly you encountered this problem.

Comment: I will confirm from him what he wants, I have a meeting soon. Thanks for your help! I'll update you soon.